# How to (fake) mipmap equirectangular rendering?

Tags: opengl, sampling, 360-degrees, 360-virtual-reality

When rendering an equirectangular encoded 360 texture, there is usually a lookup like

```
u = atan(x,z)
v = acos(y)
```

The equirectangular texture is already very prefiltered. Just turning on mipmaping does not work. `u` is not continuous and the texture itself has non uniform data in `uv`. And creating mipmaps with a 2x2 box downsample is also not right for the equirectangular.

But assuming the 2x2 box for miplevels, and hardware mipmap lookup, is there a good way to compute either lod or gradients that makes any sense?

Using just dFdx(v) and dFdy(v) kind of works to handle small viewports. But there must be a better way?

Comment: What's an 'eqirect' texture?

Comment: @ybungalobill: something like this http://photographyreel.com/image/9-narthex-equirect-panoramic-photography

Answer (score 1):

You can generate the mipmaps with `glGenerateTextureMipmap()` function and use the `texture(tex, uv)` lookup function. It will already do the job.

You should, however, normalize the `uv` coordinates so that they are in the `[0,1]` range:

```
u = atan(x,z)
v = acos(y)
uv = uv/6.283185 + .5
```

Comment: I left normalization out - it does not matter for derivatives. Just turning on mip maps like that does not work. That's the question :) glGenerate will just do a 2x2 box filter. But eqirect is already pre filtered.

Comment: @starmole: did you try that? Why it doesn't work? What do you mean by saying that your texture is already prefiltered? Don't you just load it as a 2d raster image? Can you post a sample file? My approach will definitely work for the sample file you linked -- it doen't matter if it's 'eqirect', 'webmerc' or 'lambcyl'.